# Is there a way to show datagridview rows in treeview-like form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I have a C# app I'm working on that loads a text file, parses the strings and populates a DataGridView from the parsed values. I want to show the selected row on the DataGridView in another panel with a format similar to treeview control. Is this even possible? If not a treeview control, what could I use?

**EDIT: So have this code but it is throwing a NRE:**

```
public void dataGridViewParse_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        if (dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Number"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode passFail = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["PassFail"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode cluster = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ClusterNum"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode manufacturerSpecific = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ManufacturerSpecific"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode direction = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Direction"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode disableDefaultResponse = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["DisableDefaultResponse"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode reserved = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Reserved"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode manufacturerCode = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ManufacturerCode"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode transactionSequenceNum = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["TransactionSequenceNum"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode commandID = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["CommandID"].Value.ToString());
            TreeNode framePayload = new TreeNode(dataGridViewParse.SelectedRows[0].Cells["FramePayload"].Value.ToString());


            treeView1.Nodes["Number"].Nodes.Add(id.ToString());
            treeView1.Nodes["Pass/Fail"].Nodes.Add(passFail); // throws exception here
            treeView1.Nodes["Cluster"].Nodes.Add(cluster);
            treeView1.Nodes["Manufacturer Specific"].Nodes.Add(manufacturerSpecific);
            treeView1.Nodes["Direction"].Nodes.Add(direction);
            treeView1.Nodes["Default Response"].Nodes.Add(disableDefaultResponse);
            treeView1.Nodes["Reserved"].Nodes.Add(reserved);
            treeView1.Nodes["Manufacturer Code"].Nodes.Add(manufacturerCode);
            treeView1.Nodes["Transaction Sequence Number"].Nodes.Add(transactionSequenceNum);
            treeView1.Nodes["Command Identifier"].Nodes.Add(commandID);
            treeView1.Nodes["Frame Payload"].Nodes.Add(framePayload);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Setup ad `TreeView` and then when the user clicks on a `DataGridViewRow` populate your tree by enumerating through the columns for the data grid row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any type of example?